# Spring 3 setting ThreadFactory for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, threadpool

Is this possible or is it managed by the Application Server? Passing the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor ref to a bean is a no-brainer but trying to set the threadfactory on the aforementioned executor seems to have no effect ...

Comment: and what is your question? Please clarify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, setting a `ThreadFactory` is a no-brainer as well:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="threadFactory" ref="threadFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="threadFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.CustomizableThreadFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="Custom-prefix-"/>
</bean>
```

or:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setThreadFactory(threadFactory());
    return taskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public ThreadFactory threadFactory() {
    return new CustomizableThreadFactory("Custom-prefix-");
}
```

Note that [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) extends from [`ExecutorConfigurationSupport`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html) and this is where [`setThreadFactory(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html#setThreadFactory(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)) is defined.